# SCP send Lost connection

Tags: linux, unix, scp

```
scp file.txt user1@10.57.111.44:/W/
```

Each time when I issue this SCP command, I get

```
Connection to 10.57.111.44 closed by remote host.
lost connection.
```

Why is this happening??

Comment: Check whether you can ping to that host or not?

Comment: Does "user" have access to this directory ? Does the directory exists ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the user account you're using on the remote machine has its default shell set to a valid value (e.g. /bin/bash).

To check the currently set shell use:

```
grep <username> /etc/passwd
```

(the last value in the row is the default shell). To change this value use:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash <username>
```